# How to iterate map::crbegin() without using auto keyword

Tags: c++11, stl, c++17

I have made a **map** and I want to iterate it in reverse order.
I know that i can do it by using ***auto* keyword** like this

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{ 
   map <int,int> mp;

   mp.insert(make_pair(3,30));
   mp.insert(make_pair(4,90));
   mp.insert(make_pair(2,130));
   mp.insert(make_pair(1,20));
   mp.insert(make_pair(5,10)); 

   auto it = mp.crbegin();
   while(it!=mp.crend())
   {
    cout<<it->first <<" "<< it->second <<endl;
     it++;
   }  
}
```

What can i use instead of **auto keyword** ?

My below code gives me compilation error.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{ 
  map <int,int> mp;
  mp.insert(make_pair(3,30));
  mp.insert(make_pair(4,90));
  mp.insert(make_pair(2,130));
  mp.insert(make_pair(1,20));
  mp.insert(make_pair(5,10)); 

  map<int,int>::iterator it = mp.crbegin();
  while(it!=mp.crend())
  {
    cout<<it->first <<" "<< it->second <<endl;
    it++;
  }  
}
```

Is it possible or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct nested type name is `const_reverse_iterator`. Hence, this will compile:

```
map<int,int>::const_reverse_iterator it = mp.crbegin();
```

However, controversial as `auto` might be, here it is probably common sense to use it.